# Kinect and Opencv, the depth image, how to use it

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv, kinect

I've using Kinect and OpenCV (I am using c++). I can get both the RGB and the depth image.
With the RGB image I can "play" as usual, blurring it, using canny (after converting it to greyscale),... but I can't do the same with the depth image. Each time I want to do something with the depth image I got exceptions.

I have the following code to get the depth image:

```
CvMat* depthMetersMat = cvCreateMat(480, 640, CV_16UC1 ); 
CvMat* imageMetersMat = cvCreateMat(480, 640, CV_16UC1 );
IplImage *kinectDepthImage = cvCreateImage( cvSize(640,480),16,1); 

const XnDepthPixel* pDepthMap = depth.GetDepthMap();

for (int y=0; y<XN_VGA_Y_RES; y++){ 
            for(int x=0;x<XN_VGA_X_RES;x++){ 
                depthMetersMat->data.s[y * XN_VGA_X_RES + x ] = 10 * pDepthMap[y * XN_VGA_X_RES + x]; 
          }
}

cvGetImage(depthMetersMat, kinectDepthImage);
```

The problem is that I can't do anything with kinectDepthImage. I tried to convert it to greyscale and then using canny, but I dont know how to convert it.

Basically I would like to apply canny and laplacian to the depth image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that the output from cvGetImage is 16bits depth while canny requires 8bit, therefore I need to convert it to 8bits, something like:

```
cvConvertScale(depthMetersMat, kinectDepthImage8, 1.0/256.0, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

The new OpenCV Api encurages to use Mat instead of the old image types. The current code for using the OpenNI depth meta data in OpenCV would be:

```
Mat depthMat16UC1(width, height, CV_16UC1, (void*) g_DepthMD.Data()); 
Mat depthMat8UC1;
depthMat16UC1.convertTo(depthMat8UC1, CV_8U, 1.0/256.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the sizeof(XnDepthPixel) ?

Try using a **cvCreateImageHeader** and then doing **cvSetData** on it with the XnDepth Image

Comment: The problem was that the output from cvGetImage is 16bits depth while canny requires 8bit, therefore I need to convert it to 8bits, something like:

Comment: just create an Image Header as I said with IPL_DEPTH_16U, it will be faster than converting the entire matrix, especially if is big. I want too to hack a kinect now :D

Comment: I am sorry, I am new with opencv so I don't know how to use your ideas. why I need the image header and cvSetData?

Comment: So you can use inside Opencv the SAME memory allocated by the Kinect driver. You can appreciate that copying 2D matrices is not really cheap. The image Header gives a specification of what kind of matrices he is looking at, the SetData sets the pointer to the actual matrix inside the image header structure

Answer (score 0):

Verify below link code ... could give you valuable information. NOTE: Its not my code, may give the result you require. comment the //cvCvtColor(rgbimg,rgbimg,CV_RGB2BGR);

http://pastebin.com/e5kHzs84

Regards
Nagaraju

Answer (score 0):

if you are using OpenNI, have you created context, production nodes, and started generating data? Probably that's your problem..